# Should I delete an old AWS EC2 instance after moving this old instance to a new region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've got a question in terms of AWS EC2 instance and after changing a region.

Currently, I just made to change a region for one of my instances in EC2 from U.S. Virginia to EU Frankfurt.
It went successfully though I wonder whether I should delete an old instance, the U.S. Virginia region one or not.

It's just I prefer saving the cost from EC2 then thought it might be better terminating the old instance with a region I didn't prefer to have.

Hopefully, there will be something clear answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. Either you can terminate it and its associated resource, if you are
   no longer going to use it in that region.
2. Or stop it as it will not be charged maybe charged only for storage,
       and start it when required.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll try perhaps, option 2 to see how it goes.